# NG Prime p-multiSelect disabled option not working

Tags: angular, primeng, primeng-dropdowns

I am using primeNG v7.0.3
And I have an issue with the multiSelect, namely the possibility to disable an option based on SelectItem interface.

```
this.roleOptions = [
      { label: this.messages['GLOBAL.USER.ROLE.CLINIC_USER'], value: this.roleEnum.CLINICUSER, disabled: true },
      { label: this.messages['GLOBAL.USER.ROLE.AGENT_USER'], value: this.roleEnum.AGENTUSER },
      { label: this.messages['GLOBAL.USER.ROLE.ADMIN_USER'], value: this.roleEnum.ADMINUSER },
      { label: this.messages['GLOBAL.USER.ROLE.CLINIC_REVIEWER'], value: this.roleEnum.CLINICREVIEWER }
    ];
```

The disabled CLINICUSER is still selectable. Why on earth is that still selectable?

roleOptions is initialized as `roleOptions: SelectItem[]`

Comment: Do you have a solution for this?